# How can I specify SSL certificate details for a remote WSDL which is only exposed through HTTPS with Mule ESB?

Tags: web-services, ssl, mule

I want to create a proxy to a remote web service which exposes its WSDL only through HTTPS. I have the certificate details, an I get positive response when using SOAP UI.But **I don't want to set JVM -D arguments for keystore & trustore** and need Mule SOAP Server Proxy to define them.Below is the snippet which i am using for **insecure** access to the remote service.

```
<flow name="remoteProxy" doc:name="remoteProxy">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http"
        doc:name="HTTP" />
    <cxf:proxy-service payload="envelope"
        wsdlLocation="http://remoteserver.com/service/service26?wsdl" service="ServiceName"
        namespace="http://remoteserver.com/provider/service/2012/" port="Port"
        doc:name="SOAP">
    </cxf:proxy-service>
    <https:outbound-endpoint address="http://remoteserver.com/service/service26"
        method="POST" doc:name="HTTPTo26" 
        exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
<cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope" doc:name="SOAP" />

</flow>
```

for compliance reasons I am not adding any specific details for WSDL and Endpoint. In above cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation will be HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the TLS parameters directly on your HTTPS connector configuration.

See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTPS+Transport+Reference#HTTPSTransportReference-HTTPSConnector

Comment: Thanks David it worked, one thing I noticed is that if I use <https:tls-client> later than <https:tls-key-store > and <https:tls-server> , I get parsing error on mule configuration.That's what kept me wondering about using the secured connector.

Comment: Indeed, order matters in some part of the XML configuration :)